# I can't see an IP in browser but I can ping it

Tags: networking

I have an Arduino hosting a web server that just outputs JSON data from its sensors. I have a webpage (PHP) on my intranet site that goes to that Arduino and parses the JSON. Right now I'm getting errors from the PHP saying its an invalid address. If I type the Arduino's IP address into a browser ANYWHERE on our network it shows the JSON data except on that intranet server. However I can ping the Arduino from the intranet server. I've also done a port scan from my desktop PC that shows port 80 is OPEN on the arduino but if I run the same scanner on the intranet server it shows all ports on the Arduino are closed.

The intranet server is Windows Server 2003 SBS edition (running IIS 6.0).

I've also tested this on our SBS 2011 server that runs on the same Hyper-V host as the 2003 server, and I've tested this on the host itself and both can see the JSON without a problem.

I'm a complete noob when it comes to networking, if someone can at least point me in the correct direction I would be most grateful!

Comment: "*If I type the Arduino's IP address into a browser ANYWHERE on our network it shows the JSON data except on that intranet server.*" You forgot to describe the problem! What happens when try to access the Arduino from the Intranet server? Do you get an error? How, precisely, does it fail?

Comment: does your domain suffix end in .local?

Comment: Yes our domain suffix is .local, and when I type the IP address into IE it returns "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" as if the Arduino doesn't exist on the network